# Continuity and derivability of a multivariable function at a specific point

Tags: piecewise, discontinuity

I have this function:

```
f = Sqrt(Abs(x^2 - x*y))
```

So, how can I prove that it is derivable and/or continue in a point, like (0,0)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good question for learning purpose. Let us somewhat refine the definition of the function under consideration:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[RealAbs[x^2 - x*y]]
```

We start from the verification of  [its continuity at the origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) through

```
Limit[f[x, y], {x, y} -> {0, 0}] == f[0, 0]
(*True*)
```

Next, in order to test [its differentiability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables) at the origin, we find its partial derivatives at the origin by

```
Limit[(f[x, y] /. y -> 0 - f[0, 0])/x, x -> 0]
(*Indeterminate*)
```

and the analogous limit for the partial derivative by $y$.
Since the partial derivative by $x$ does not exist at the origin, the function under consideration is not differentiable at the origin.

Try another point on your own.

Addition. On the OP's request, let

```
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*Cos[x*y]
```

Then

```
D[f[x, y], x] /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}
(*0*)
```

and

```
 D[f[x, y], y] /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}
(*1*)
```

Up to the definition of the differentiability , the condition

```
Limit[(f[x, y] - f[0, 1] + 0*(x - 0) - 1*(y - 1))/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2],{x, y}-> {0, 1}] == 0
(*True*)
```

should be tested in this case.

**Edit.** It should be

```
Limit[(f[x, y] - f[0, 1] + 0*(x - 0) - 1*(y - 1))/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 1)^2], {x, y} -> {0, 1}] == 0
(*0*)
```

in the above. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Ok, It worked but now..
With this function:
`Log[x*y]`
if we find its partial derivatives at the (0,1) it say
`Limit[(f[x, y] /. y -> 1 - f[0, 1])/x, x -> 0]
(*Indeterminate*)`
But it is clearly 0.
Analogous, the limit for the partial derivate by is 
`Limit[(f[x, y] /. x -> 0 - f[0, 1])/y, y -> 1] (*Sqrt(2)*Cos[1]` but it is clearly 1.

Comment: @Teodoro Coluccio: Mathematica is right because the function `Log[x*y]` is not defined at the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Teodoro Coluccio: The command `FunctionDomain[Log[x*y], {x, y}]//FullSimplify` results in `x y > 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I wrong to copy the function.. The correct it's this: `Sqrt[x^2+y^2]*Cos[x*y]` 
Now the partial derivatives at (0,1) are 0 and 1..

Comment: @Teodoro Coluccio:  I added that example to my answer.